# Last decision meaning final

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "last" in this context meaning that the young woman makes the final decision?
"Whether or not she agrees to be a surrogate mother is up to her. Her mother should not intefere. The young woman's decision should be last not her mother's."

Comment: To put it simply, we normally use _final_ for a decision which affects the outcome of a situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Last' is a simple word / set of intercategorial polysemes with complex distributions (yes, I've gone for the plural):

from [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/last_1?q=last+):

> **Last** can be used in the following ways:
>
> - as a determiner (followed by a noun): *I saw him last night. I wasn’t here last time.*
> - as an adjective (after a determiner and before a noun): *My last job was in London. I ate the last piece of cake.*
>
>   - (after the verb ‘to be’ [and 'to finish', 'to be placed', 'to come']): *I was last in the race. ['A Good Day to Die Hard' comes last
>     in the series]*
> - as a pronoun (after ‘the’): *Their new CD is even better than the last. And that was the last I saw of him.*
> - as an adverb: *When did you see him last? I put my shoes on last.*
> - as a noun (followed by ‘of’): *I drank up the last of the wine.*

While I'd disagree that 'last' is an adjective in the examples given (its role is still to point out reference in a given context rather than describe inherent attributes), we can note that the [determiner] use *after the verb 'be' etc* is 'the final one in an obvious series'. A race, an exam, a series of books or films. This seems to be a restriction that Macmillan misses.

There are less than 10 distinct hits in a Google search for "decision should be last" (go to page 2 for the corrected figure), and one of the quotes contains an on-the-hoof correction: ' "Our decision should be last, final." Hart replied ...' [[Daily Chronicle, De Kalb, Illinois](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22decision+should+be+last%22&ei=5QhaX834EIWZ1fAPrvisgAE&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiN__GRud7rAhWFTBUIHS48CxAQ8NMDegQICxAv&biw=1327&bih=750&dpr=1.25)]

*'The young woman's decision should be last' does not fulfil this requirement; 'final', carrying the sense of 'the last word on the subject', is the idiomatic choice here. 'The young woman's decision should be the last one to be entertained' *is* acceptable, but clunky.

(Note that it would not be impossible to find a contrived context where 'The young woman's decision should be last' *would* be acceptable.)

Comment: Interesting.  "Last, final.." is not impossible. But "last" alone is not the best choice. If I understand correctly.

Comment: I'd say Hart, realising that 'last' didn't sound right here, corrected himself to 'final'.

Comment: Thank you very much.